# Play framework(2.2.4) server becoming unresponsive

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, netty

We have a play **2.2.4** (JDK **1.7**) application with Mysql database in production, for which the server **occasionally** becomes unresponsive.

Looking at server and JVM stats, we noticed that the java process shows very high(90%-100%) CPU usage during the time when the application becomes unresponsive.

---

When we deploy our application, we noticed that it creates multiple processes with the same command as used to run the application. (All these processes are killed, if we kill the main application process)

[image: Multiple processes]

We deployed a sample play application, and in that case too, multiple processes are created but less in number compared to our application.

One of my question is, why does play create these processes, and how to find out what each of these processes does?

---

We have tried increasing the heap memory for the JVM but the problem still persists.

The application starts working when we when we stop and restart the server.

Any help is appreciated.